# How to mask a video frame using contours with opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matplotlib

I am using opencv (cv2 module) in python to recognize objects in a video. In each frame, I want to extract a particular region aka, the contour. After learning from [opencv docs](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_begins/py_histogram_begins.html?highlight=calchist), I have the following code snippet:

```
        # np is numpy module, contours are expected results,
        # frame is each frame of the video

        # Iterate through the contours.
        for contour in contours:
            # Compute the bounding box for the contour, draw
            # it on the frame, and update the text.
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

            # Find the mask and build a histogram for the object.
            mask = np.zeros(frame.shape[:2], np.uint8)
            mask[y:h, x:w] = 255
            masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)
            obj_hist = cv2.calcHist([masked_img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
```

However, when I use `matplotlib` to show the `masked_img`, it returns a dark image. The `obj_hist` has only one element with number greater than `0`, which is the first one. What is wrong?

Comment: @boardrider I have edited it, hopefully this could help you understand my question :-)

Comment: Have you verified that `contours` contains anything?

Comment: @MikeC Yes, `contours` is fine, I can detect new objects with it. but I failed extracting the certain region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are setting the values in your mask.  Specifically this line:

```
mask[y:h, x:w] = 255
```

You are trying to slice into each dimension of the image by using `y:h` and `x:w` to set up the mask.  The left of the colon is the starting row or column, and the right of the colon denotes the **end** row or column.  Given that you start at `y`, you need to **offset** by `h` using the same reference `y`... the same goes for `x` and `w`.

Doing the slicing where the right value of the colon is less than the left will not modify the array in any way, and that's most why you aren't getting any output as you are not modifying the mask when it's initially all zeroes.

You probably meant to do:

```
mask[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255
```

This will properly set the proper region given by `cv2.boundingRect` to white (255).